# Logging in to Craiglist with PHP

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, craigslist

I want my website to have access to my listings on Craigslist. My plan is to scrape the page at https://accounts.craigslist.org/login/home. However, in order to access this page, I need to log in. How can I log in with PHP and then get the content hidden behind?

I've tried using curl like this:

```
$url = "https://accounts.craigslist.org/login";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"inputEmailHandle=MYEMAIL&inputPassword=MYPASSWORD");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

However, I get a 404 error from cragslist. What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: In case you were unaware about the entire http protocol. `404` == page does not exist.

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 2);` Not sure you have this set to do, but it should either be true or false http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: this would breach craiglists' terms of useage

Comment: @Augwa that was intended to be a count of the vars, based on another site I read. I changed it to true and I still face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at symfony browserkit component.

> The BrowserKit component simulates the behavior of a web browser, allowing you to make requests, click on links and submit forms programmatically

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/browser_kit.html

I'm using it to bypass login screens but as someone mentioned earlier, make sure you read terms

Answer (score 0):

```php
$url = "https://accounts.craigslist.org/login";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"inputEmailHandle=MYEMAIL&inputPassword=MYPASSWORD");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).